# Accordion doesn't work correctly on click

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem.

My accordion doesn't work correctly, when the page loads for the fist time, I must double click on it.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

In my scss File, the "nextSibling" is set to `display none`.

Here is my JS Code:

```
let accordionHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName("accordions__header");

for(let header of accordionHeaders) {
    header.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (this.nextElementSibling.style.display == "none") {
            this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
        }else{
            this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done, can you add those details? Is the click handler fired on the first click? Did you add a console log to make sure the event listener is set? What is the value of `display`?

Comment: `.style.display` doesn't get the calculated style, it gets the defined style props. I imagine you haven't explicitly set a `display` style on your element. (You'd be better off adding style using a class, and checking for the existence of that)

Comment: @DBS I think this is the actual answer, the first click sets the element to `display: none`, then you need a second click to set it to `block`

Comment: @Marco consider also the option of using [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) when you'll better improve your strategy

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
let accordionHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(".accordions__header");

Array.from(accordionHeaders).forEach(header => {
    header.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display == "none") e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
        else e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

use e.target instead of this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).